# Transforming an uniform random variable to a bernoulli-variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Given is an uniform random variable in the interval [1,3].
The goal is to describe a transformation from this variable to a bernoulli variable with p = 0.6.

It is quite "obvious" that one could assign 0.6*(3-1)+1 to the "successes" and the rest of the interval to the "fails" (or vice versa), but how can this transformation be described in a formal way?

Comment: Have you heard of "indicator function" or "Iverson Bracket"?

Comment: I see, so you would define it with X = 1 if X in 0.6*(3-1)+1 and X = 0 else?

Answer (score 0):

Given that $X\sim\text{Unif}(1,3)$, consider

\begin{eqnarray*}Y_1 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } X \leq 2.2 \\ 0 & \text{if } X > 2.2\end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}Y_2 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } |X-2| \leq 0.6 \\ 0 & \text{if } |X-2| > 0.6 \end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}Y_3 = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } |X-2| \geq 0.4 \\ 0 & \text{if } |X-2| < 0.4 \end{cases} \end{eqnarray*}

Here $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3\sim\text{Bernoulli}(0.6)$.

Answer (score -2):

Of course, your method is OK. But I think you're looking
at a more formal or standard way to do this.

You could apply the 'inverse CDF' (also called 'quantile function') of the Bernoulli random variable to random observations from
$\mathsf{Unif}(0, 1)$ [stamdard uniform]. In R, the quantile function of Bernoulli with $p = 0.6$ is
`qbinom` with parameters $n = 1$ and $p = 0.6.$

You can get standard uniform $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0, 1)$ from
$V \sim \mathsf{Unif}(1,3),$ with $U = (V - 1)/2.$

When the quantile plot of a distribution is available, it is often used in this way to simulate random samples from the distribution.

In R, the code for 10,000 realizations of the desired Bernoulli random variable is as follows:

```
set.seed(322)
v = runif(10000, 1, 3)
u = (v - 1)/2
x = qbinom(u, 1, 0.6)
table(x)
x
   0    1 
4018 5982
```

So we get about 6000 Successes and 4000 Failures, which matches the anticipated results from a bernoulli random variable with $p = 0.6.$

Here are histograms of the 10,000 $U$'s and $V$'s.

[image]

In the left panel below is a plot of the quantile function of $\mathsf{Bern}(.6).$ [Values of $X$ below 0.4, produxe Failures and those above 0.4 produce Successes.]

The right panel shows and Empirical CDF plot (ECDF) of the sample of 10,000 observations from that distribution. [The ECDF is very nearly the same as the CDF, except that it reflects 5982 Successes out of 10,000, instead of exactly 60% successes.]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though I am not looking for code, but for an explicit analytic transformation from one random variable to the other

Comment: Well, I was sort of hoping you could work that part out from seeing the quantile function and the results.